# See process flow of shipping table rate module

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, shipping-methods, table-rates, free-shipping

I would like to know if there is an extension/way that let me see the complete flow of the passages of how the rate is choosen, because I have a module that let me choose only one free shipping method to apply to shopping cart price rule, so I guess that something does a check to see if it is equal to something, but I can't find the "breakpoint" to edit this behaviour.
I have tried to install AOE_profiler, but php return an error about `"header already sent"` or `PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'TYPE_DATABASE' in app/code/community/Zend/Db/Profiler.php`.
 Now I have installed `Developer Toolbar` from MGT, but I think that it isn't complete (or maybe I don't know where I have to look).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no extension*, but xdebug let you step through the code, to get a feeling for the flow.

*At least I don't know any and don't see any need for this, so maybe no one else would implement such.